# In Django using all auth i want to make a custom API without REST framework for following info i provided below

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

In this  i will enter UID ,email,username using POSTMAN and it will check whether uid exist or not,if it exist it will login user,if it did not and if same email exist in User model,it will create entry for same email in social account table along with generating token,so user can login through social email id also.Can u explain me which method or what should i use to create all entries and generate  token.I will also specify logintype in POSTMAN as like google or facebook.and if user does not exist in user table also,it will create new one using email and username

Answer (score 0):

To Request data from a user model and check if it exists if/else then create new row. The code is the following.

```
    try:
        obj = Person.objects.get(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
    except Person.DoesNotExist:
        obj = Person(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon', birthday=date(1940, 10, 9))
        obj.save()
```

there is another way of doing the same thing and its using one of it's internal functions.

```
bj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
    first_name='John',
    last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)},
)
```

NOTE: To handle HTTP Requests. and get a URL you need to use the urls.py and the views.py to create a function with the logic that you are mentioning. after this. go to your urls.py and link the function or class to your URL inside urls.py for your REST API Path (e.g. /api/new/user/)

To generate a UUID like facebook you need to modify your models.py and add this following.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    uuid_key = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

If this isn't enough data. you can make use of the signal feature in Django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/

This will execute a CRUD Operation or other logic you want as soon something happens to your model querySet.

So you can lets say,

- Update information after a QuerySet
- Delete other information after a QuerySet
- Make a calculation after a QuerySet.

Here is how to use it by example: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: I know this, i want to generate social user based on email i entered in POSTMAN that already exist is USER model,it should generate data like token and extra_data attribute of both tables social account and social application tokens.I am using allauth package for social login